# Populate hidden field value from hidden div title text

Tags: jquery, hidden-field

I have 6 hidden divs with different ID (#One, #Two, #Three...) that show by an image click, each one has different class (.one-trigger, .two-trigerr....).
Every hidden div has a different title with same class and the same form.
The form contains a hidden field with no value.
I'm trying to get the title's text in the hidden field value, based on the div that is no visible, or by the trigger clicked.
This is the html markup:

```
<img class="one-trigger"/>
<img class="two-trigger"/>
.
.
.
<div id="One">
<h2 class="get-title">this is the title 1</h2>
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="the-title" id="the-title" value=""/>
</div>

<div id="Two">
<h2 class="get-title">this is the title 2</h2>
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="the-title" id="the-title" value=""/>
</form>
</div>
```

So far i tried this jquery code, that gets the title text, but does not change when showing different divs:

```
$(function() {
$('input[name="the-title"]').val($(".get-title").text());
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, that I've understood you clearly. Hope this is what you need:

```
$('input[name="the-title"]').each(function(key, value) {
  $(value).val($($(value).parents()[1]).find(".get-title").text());
});
```

Also, you have duplicate id's on your inputs. Fix it.